# Rearranging Inventory in Fallout Shelter

Tags: steam, fallout-shelter

**Is there a way to rearrange the items in your inventory in Fallout Shelter?** For example, I would like to put all of my single-stat outfits at the beginning, then two-stat and three and so-on. I checked out this [IGN tip-list](http://www.ign.com/wikis/fallout-shelter/Advanced_Vault_Tips), but with no luck. My question *is* similar to this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/falloutshelter/comments/3huu6m/question_managing_inventory/) in that it seeks better management of inventory items, but all I am looking for is the ability to customize the arrangement of items. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I just had the idea that, since the order is dependent upon the order in which you fill your inventory, you *could* customize it by deleting everything in the inventory and then selectively crafting what you want in which order (once you have all the recipes, anyway). However, I very much dislike this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot sort your inventory in Fallout Shelter. Items and apparel will be listed in the order they were recovered, crafted, or acquired.

You can sort your dwellers, however, by opening the vault dweller list and selected the "Dwellers" header on the top to sort alphabetically or the "Job" header to sort by their assigned task. This functionality does not exist when viewing your vault's inventory.